# Slash commands in cog aren't visible on discord pycord

Tags: python, discord, command, pycord

I have a moderation cog, it is loaded correctly but the slash commands aren't visible, while every listener on the cog works

Here is a command I wrote in moderation cog:

```py
class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    servers = ["My serv Id here"]

    @commands.slash_command(name="clear", guild_ids=servers)
    @default_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clear_cmd(self, ctx, number: discord.Option(discord.SlashCommandOptionType.integer, required=True)):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=number)
```

I don't see this command when i type "/" on discord, I only see the ones i wrote in the main.py file, the load function is correctly called and when i tried to add a `Cog.listener` `on_message` in the moderation cog, it was working. Also, the `on_ready` listener doesn't work in the cog.

Comment: Did you make sure to input the guild as an INT and not a STR ("ID")?

Comment: Are the commands synced? Was the cog loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes the guild is an int and the cog is loaded, but how can i sync it?

Comment: @MIFO77 sometimes if you try to override the on_connect function, you can accidentally not get bot command syncing. Have you overridden the on_connect function?

Comment: @BlueRobin I don't think I did but can you tell me how can i do that and how to stop doing it, and i'll check in my code if anything matches that

Comment: @MIFO77 if you did the bot.event decorator and then the on_connect function, it'll be overriden

Comment: @BlueRobin nop i didn't do that, though i think i didn't sync my commands, and i don't know how to do that in pycord, i only found some stuff for discord.py with `slash = SlashCommand(sync_command=True)`

Comment: @MIFO77 are the servers in the `servers` variable of type int in the list?